# How to move XML bean definition to @Configuration annotated class

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, queue, jms

I am new to Spring, I am working in moving some bean definitions from XML to @Configuration Class.

Here is one of the beans I am struggling with:

```
<bean id="jmsProducerTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate"
      p:connectionFactory-ref="connectionFactory"/>

<jms:listener-container container-type="default" 
                        connection-factory="connectionFactory"
                        acknowledge="auto">

<jms:listener destination="YOURQUEUENAME" ref="theListenerClassYouAreUsing" />

</jms:listener-container>
```

How would that look in a @Configuration class, thanks.

So far I have this

```
@Bean("myContainerFactory")
public JmsListenerContainerFactory myContainerFactory() {
    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();

    ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = pooledConnectionFactory();

   
    factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory);
    factory.setPubSubDomain(false);

    return factory;
}
```

I am missing the destination set, no idea how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add a listener as well, see for example [Annotation-driven Listener Endpoints](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/integration.html#jms-annotated):

```
@Component
public class MyService {

    @JmsListener(destination = "YOURQUEUENAME", containerFactory = "myContainerFactory")
    public void myListener(String data) { ... }
}
```